# Does the Ring of Free Action grant immunity to the incapacitated condition if caused by magic?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items, conditions

I am a DM who is planning to have the party finally face off against a criminal mastermind whose signature spell is Modify Memory. However, the party rogue is in possession of a Ring of Free Action.

One of the effects of the [Ring of Free Action](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/ring-of-free-action) is to make it impossible for magic to reduce your speed:

> While you wear this ring, difficult terrain doesn't cost you extra movement. **In addition, magic can neither reduce your speed nor cause you to be paralyzed or restrained.**

The [Modify Memory](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/modify-memory) spell causes the target to be charmed and incapacitated for the duration, and one of the effects of the [incapacitated](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/appendix-a-conditions#Incapacitated) condition is the inability to move.

Does the Ring of Free Action provide immunity to the incapacitated condition if it was caused by magic?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Answer (score 14):

### No, the *ring of free action* doesn't prevent being incapacitated

The incapacitated condition is separate from the restrained and paralyzed conditions (it being inflicted by the latter is irrelevant here) and is not a reduction to speed.<sup>†</sup> Thus, neither of these effects give immunity to being incapacitated.

If the ring had given immunity to the incapacitated condition, it would have said so (probably by listing it among the other mentioned conditions).

---

† The incapacitated condition is inflicted by some other conditions (paralyzed, stunned, unconscious) which do prevent movement. However the full effect of the [incapacitated](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/appendix-a-conditions#Incapacitated) condition alone is (per Appendix A of the PHB/Basic Rules):

> - An incapacitated creature can't take actions or reactions.

In 5e, movement is wholly separate from actions (and reactions).